# Travel insurance cover for lost or stolen passport?

Tags: schengen, passports, lost-documents, travel-insurance-claim

I am indian citizen. I applied for travel insurance cover (180 days) when i was about to visit schengen countries.

Last week my handbag was stolen in Spain, with that passport, residence permit all lost. The incident happened when i had cover and i filed a police report and also notified embassy.

I finally contacted the insurance company, they say insurance cover for lost passport possible, but, it does not cover for stolen passport. see below their email response..

> Loss of Passport Claim Procedure   The list of documents required to
>   be attached with the claim are as follows:   •       Duly Signed Claim
>   Form stating exact circumstances of loss •       Copy of FIR (first
>   information report)/Police Report. •       Receipts related to
>   expenses incurred to obtain a new passport •       NEFT form and Pre
>   Printed Cancelled cheque stating insured's / Claimant Indian Bank
>   account details •       Passport and visa copy with Entry Stamp
>   Overseas and exit Stamp from India if applicable
>
> Also note :    We would regret to inform you that theft/robbery is
>   not covered under this insurance as per policy terms and condition .

Since my handbag was stolen, passport was inside handbag. does that mean my passport also stolen, and i am not eligible for claim?

Please clarify the difference between lost passport and stolen passport in this case!

Here is the wording of the insurance company policy:

> Section E: Loss of Passport
>   In the event of the Insured's loss of his passport, the Company will
>   pay
>
> the Insured the Section E Sum Assured (less the deductible) specified
>   in
>
> the Schedule towards expenses necessarily incurred by the Insured in
>
> obtaining a duplicate or fresh passport.
>
> Exclusions Applicable to Section E
>
> The Company shall be under no liability to make payment for:
>
> Loss or damage to the Insured's passport as a result of the
>   confiscation
>
> or detention by customs, police or any other authority.

Comment: We'd really need to see the actual language of the fine print on the insurance policy, and even then it's more of a question of legal interpretation than travel. But if the policy really only does cover loss and not theft, it certainly sounds like your passport was stolen. I can't see how a bag can be stolen while the items inside it are lost.

Comment: ANAL, but generally in 'legaleese', 'loss' means any circumstance which results in you no longer having possession of something. 'Lost' doesn't exclusively mean 'misplaced'. Having something stolen is certainly a 'loss' of this something. So if confiscation is the only exclusion then you should be covered. I'd call them back and push harder - insist that they show you the section of the policy which excludes theft.

Comment: Somewhere in your policy's terms & conditions should be a page with definitions of terms, which should specify what they mean by "loss".  That definition of "loss" will be the deciding factor and nothing more.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is "stolen passport insurance" supposed to cover? The fee for issuing a new one at the embassy?

Comment: Insurance covers upto USD 250 for loss of passport.

Comment: You need to push harder. Unless explicitly stated in their terms and conditions that theft/robber is not considered under loss, you have a right to the insurance coverage. In common usage, loss of your passport is loss, whether you misplaced it or it was stolen. They're just trying to avoid paying up.

Comment: Yes, "loss" is almost certainly defined somewhere in the policy, and exactly how that is defined makes a big difference. Ultimately though, your options are pretty much limited to continuing to argue with them, complaining to a regulatory authority if there is one, perusing a legal case that will cost far more than it's worth, or giving up.

Comment: I'm afraid we are not lawyers - the text is there, and all you can do is argue with the insurance company, and failing that, a lawyer could do so on your behalf. Us guessing if it's covered seems unlikely to be productive :/